# SnowMaker .Net library for Azure

Tags: vb.net, azure, singleton

I am using the above library in my vb.net web app. The person who developed snowmaker said that you shouldn't create a new instance every time you want an ID, you should use a basic singleton.

I know what singletons are, but have never used them. I have come across this on stack overflow

```
Public NotInheritable Class MySingleton
    Private Shared ReadOnly _instance As New Lazy(Of MySingleton)(Function() New
        MySingleton(), System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication)

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance() As MySingleton
        Get
            Return _instance.Value
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Here is the code I'm using to generate the ID's

```
Dim storageAccount As CloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("blobStorage").ConnectionString)
Dim ds As New BlobOptimisticDataStore(storageAccount, "container-name")

Dim generator = New UniqueIdGenerator(ds)
Dim ret = generator.NextId(table)
```

which works, but how do I incorporate that into the singleton class so that I only call it once from my web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A singleton is a static object that you can call as many times as you want and be assured that it will only run one call at a time.

You don't instantiate a singleton, it is like a class level or global object that you just call.  You havent included the code for UniqueIdGenerator, but your code might look something like this:

```
Imports SnowMaker
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
        Dim ds As New BlobOptimisticDataStore(storageAccount, "vhds")

        MySingleton.Instance.DataSource = ds
        MySingleton.Instance.Table = "table"
        Dim myid = MySingleton.Instance.NextId
        Dim myid2 = MySingleton.Instance.NextId
        Dim myid3 = MySingleton.Instance.NextId
        Dim myid4 = MySingleton.Instance.NextId

    End Sub

End Module
```

Then your singleton code would call your generator

```
Imports SnowMaker

Public NotInheritable Class MySingleton
    Private Shared ReadOnly _instance = New Lazy(Of MySingleton)(Function() New MySingleton(), System.Threading.LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication)
    Private _generator As UniqueIdGenerator

    Private Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance() As MySingleton
        Get
            Return _instance.Value
        End Get
    End Property

    Private _ds As BlobOptimisticDataStore
    Public Property DataSource() As BlobOptimisticDataStore
        Get
            Return _ds
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As BlobOptimisticDataStore)
            _ds = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _tableName As String
    Public Property Table() As String
        Get
            Return _tableName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _tableName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Id As Integer
    Public ReadOnly Property NextId() As Integer
        Get
            If _generator Is Nothing Then
                _generator = New UniqueIdGenerator(_ds)
            End If
            Return _generator.NextId(_tableName)
        End Get
    End Property

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still have no clue. When I paste that into visual studio 2012 I get all kinds of intelisense errors.

Basically all I'm doing is this, which works when you call it

        `Dim storageAccount As CloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("blobStorage").ConnectionString)
        Dim ds As New BlobOptimisticDataStore(storageAccount, "xploite-ids")

        Dim generator = New UniqueIdGenerator(ds)
        Dim orderNumber = generator.NextId("orderNumbers")`

Comment: But, running it multiple times gives you the following ID numbers back

1, 101, 201, 301

That is because the ids are issued in batches of 100. What I'm trying to do is get 1, 2, 3, 4, ie only running the function once the batch has ran out. There are no examples that I can find anywhere.

Comment: Basically, you need to push in the datasource and table once, but call the nextid multiple times.

Comment: The nextID method is part of the snowmaker package dll

Comment: See here http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2011/07/14/released-snowmaker-a-unique-id-generator-for-azure-or-any-other-cloud-hosting-environment/

Comment: I see now.  Your only issue is that you need to separate the calling of the "new UniqueIdGenerator" from the calling of NextId().  Where do you get the variable "table" from?

Comment: Table is what I want to pass to the function when I want a new Id, so table is the tablename in the DB that I want the ID for

Comment: The variable Table basically tells the blob storage client what blob to access